# NoReverseMatch: Django URL

Tags: python, django

I cannot display the products in the ProductDetailView.

ProductDetailView is returning empty string to 'category-detail'..

In Product Detail View it links to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/products/6/
```

but returns this Error:

```
Reverse for 'category_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/categories/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']
```

The Information shows up fine in list view for both category and product.

urls.py

```
    url(r'^categories/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category_detail'),
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    """
    Model For a product category
    """

    c_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Enter a Product Category: ")


    def __str__(self):
        """
        String Representation for the Model object
        """
        return self.c_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Return an absolute URL to access a product instance
        """
        return reverse('category_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

views.py

```
class CategoryDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'category_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'category_detail'
    paginate_by = 2
    model = Category

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(self.model, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['products'] = self.get_object().products.all()
        return context


class ProductDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'product_detail'
    template_name = 'product_detail.html'
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(self.model, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])    

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context
```

html

```
  <p><strong>Category:</strong> <a href="{% url 'category_detail' product.category.pk %}">{{ product.category }}</a></p>
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take out the context names

```
class CategoryDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    ...
    context_object_name = 'category_detail' # 
     ...

class ProductDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    ...
    context_object_name = 'product_detail.html'
    ...
```

These are messing with the linking system.

Another thing.. in the product_detail.html. you need to add the product.pk into the url

```
      <a href="{% url 'product-update' product.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">update</a>

      <a href="{% url 'product-delete' product.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a>
```

This Should work..

Also maybe link back to the product-detail view when you have finished editing the product :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your `CategoryDetailView` need `get_object`.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
...


class CategoryDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'category_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'category_detail'
    paginate_by = 2
    model = Category

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(self.model, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['products'] = self.get_object().products.all()
        return context
```

and change the url;

```
url(r'^categories/(?P<pk>\d+)$', ...
```

to:

```
url(r'^categories/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ...
```

Comment: Hi I still get the error:

Reverse for 'category-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/categories/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']..

Comment: I have updated my question with your suggestions. I think I may have already tried but I have been going in circles for a while now lol